# script to change the account name entries

Tags: sharepoint-server

Hi am on SharePoint 2010 and we have configured adfs to the web app and i am looking for writing a script to rename user account entries in site from “c:0-.t|adfs|” to “c:0-.t|adfs|”. currently i am getting th eaccount name as c:0-.t|adfs|. some one has ever worked on this .thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: could you please tell us what you want to change? becuase all you want to change is same like c:0-.t|adfs|....

Comment: hi waqas i am trying to change to rename user account entries in site from “c:0-.t|adfs|<distinguishName for group>” to “c:0-.t|adfs|<groupName>” where distinguishname implies which shows in the image above. I just want to rename it to c:0-t|adfs|<groupName> only. thanks.

Comment: I just want c:0-.t|adfs|<groupName> i dont want the rest after groupname to be shown as you can see in fig. which is having those non required characters. thanks